# list exported functions from dll with ctypes

Tags: python, dll, shared-libraries, ctypes

Is there any way to know which functions are exported from the `dll` through python foreign function library `ctypes`?

And if possible to know details about the exported functions through c`types`.

If yes, could someone provide a snippet of code?

Answer (score 25):

If you are on Linux, there is a handy utility `nm` to list the content of a shared library (there is always a handy utility on Linux, especially for C stuff).

[Here is the question about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514745/how-do-i-view-the-list-of-functions-a-linux-shared-library-is-exporting)

You use it with the `-D` flag: `nm -D ./libMyLib.so`

Answer (score 22):

I don't think ctypes offers this functionality.  On Windows with visual studio:

```
DUMPBIN -EXPORTS XXX.DLL
```

Or for mingw on windows:

```
objdump -p XXX.dll
```

Answer (score 8):

In general, this is not possible, because, again in general, dynamically loaded libraries do not carry the meta-information you require.  It may be possible to obtain that information in certain special cases through system-specific ways, but `ctypes` itself does not fetch that information.  You can *record* such info via `ctypes` (see e.g. the [restype](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#ctypes._FuncPtr.restype) and `argtypes` attributes of function pointers), but only after you have obtained it by different means.

Comment: The answer given by @Mark contradicts your answer as it provides the information that you claim doesn't exist in a DLL. As far as I understand the mingw family of C compilers newer DLLs can be linked by name, while older ones required to know the index to the address table before linking the  executable together.

Answer (score 6):

The below approach worked for both Windows and Ubuntu. For Windows, [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com) is required.

Suppose, there is a `c` file like below which name is `test.c`.

```
int func1(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

int func2(int a, int b){
    return a - b;
}
```

And the above c codes were compiled to `test.dll` file with the below commands:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,adder -o test.dll -fPIC test.c
```

And the below Python script finds which functions of the `test.dll` can be used by Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

out = Popen(
    args="nm ./test.dll", 
    shell=True, 
    stdout=PIPE
).communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")

attrs = [
    i.split(" ")[-1].replace("\r", "") 
    for i in out.split("\n") if " T " in i
]

from ctypes import CDLL

functions = [i for i in attrs if hasattr(CDLL("./test.dll"), i)]

print(functions)
```

The output I got in Windows is as below:

```
['func1', 'func2']
```

The output I got in Ubuntu is as below:

```
['_fini', 'func1', 'func2', '_init']
```

The items of the above list are objects of `_FuncPtr` class.

Answer (score 5):

@Mark's answer uses Visual Studio tools.

On windows you can also use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to get the function names of dll exports.

Sometimes names are mangled and can't be used as a valid python function name.

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to get a handle to mangled functions, e.g:

```
mylib = ctypes.cdll('mylib.dll')
my_func = getattr(mylib, '_my_func@0')

my_func()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you've also got the source for said library, and you're looking for a fully automated all-python way, you could use `pycparser`

for the file: `prog.c`

```
typedef short int ret_t;
typedef short int param_t;

ret_t add(param_t a, param_t b) {
    return (ret_t)(a + b);
}

ret_t passthrough(ret_t (* func)(param_t a, param_t b), param_t a, param_t b) {
    // parameter intentionally altered.
    // if this isn't done, compiler will deem entire function redundant
    return func(a, b + 1);
}
```

compiling with `gcc`

```
gcc -I. -E ./prog.c > prog-preproc.c
```

gives us the pre-processed c file: `prog-preproc.c`
then in python:

```
import pycparser
parser = pycparser.c_parser.CParser()

with open('prog-preproc.c', 'r') as fh:
    ast = parser.parse(fh.read())

class FunctionVisitor(pycparser.c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_FuncDef(self, node):
        print("found function: %s" % node.decl.name)
        #node.show()

FunctionVisitor().visit(ast)
```

yields

```
found function: add
found function: passthrough
```

To dig further you can also get parameter and return types.
Uncomment `node.show()` for more information from within the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)

*edit*: I've written a library to do a lot of the heavy lifting on this : https://github.com/fragmuffin/prlsc/tree/main/lib/py (examples can be found in that project)

Answer (score 1):

YES! there is a very clever native method to do it.

let's say you are using Python ctypes. put something like this in your C code:

1) in your C code:

```
#define PYEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```

now put PYEXPORT above the function you want to export:

```
PYEXPORT
int myfunc(params){
```

2) After compiling, go back into Python and open your .c file, and parse it similar to this:

```
source1_ = open(cfile_name + '.c')
source1 = source1_.read()
source1_.close()
fn = source1.split('PYEXPORT')[-1].split('(')[0].split(' ')[1]
```

shell input: fn

shell output: 'myfunc'

3) Now here's the clever part: define a new function in a string:

```
a1 = """
global get_c_fn
def get_c_fn(dll):
     func = dll."""
a2 = """
return func"""
a3 = a1 + fn + a2

print(a3)
global get_c_fn
def get_c_fn(dll):
    func = dll.myfunc
    return func
```

NOW do exec(a3) and it will turn that string into a function that you can use.

4) do the usual:

```
mydll = ctypes.CDLL(cfile_name + '.dll')
c_fn = get_cuda_fn(mydll)
c_fn.argtypes =  func_params (an array of C-converted inputs you need)
c_fn( *[params] )
```

and there you have a python wrapper for a C script without having to modify ten different things every time something changes.

Answer (score 0):

Internally ctypes uses functions provided by dynamic link library (dlopen/dlsym on unix,  LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress on windows) to load library and find address of function specified by function name; and then use cffi library to pass parameter dynamically.

Problem is that the dynamic link library that ctypes depends on doesn't include function to list symbol from the shared library, that's why you can't list symbol by ctypes.

To do that, you have to use specific tools to dump elf file (readelf on unix) and pe file for dll (dumpbin on windows).

Comment: This is really interesting... I used Wumpbin to find what is in the library... How can I use it now? I'd need to know if it works using parameters or not...