# C / Python ctypes shared object introspection libraries/techniques

Tags: python, object, ctypes, shared

I was looking for a way to list .text section defined symbols on a C shared object loaded on a python program using the ctypes wrapper. In other words, i am trying to get a list of defined functions on a CDLL loaded object.

If there is no way to do this with ctypes or library ( or python binding ), another option is a python elf parsing library or a solution like http://halflifelibrary.com/wiki/Metamod-P.

Any way to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891493/list-exported-functions-from-dll-with-ctypes

Comment: Nope, that question points to specific ctypes solution i am looking for C shared object introspection libraries/techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI there is no way to get a list of defined methods on a shared object loaded using ctypes because there is no meta information on the object structure.

If you need a platform specific object parser maybe you should take a look at http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/wiki/MicrosoftToolchainSupport using the objdump routines to get defined function references on the text section.

My option do this is to write a small parser using a ELF parser library like [Hachoir](http://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/hachoir-parser) or the [Pydevtools](http://code.google.com/p/pydevtools/) in order to introspect the object.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the list of methods that you are trying to use to get the list of functions that is exported by the dll.

There is a script at : http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/wiki/MicrosoftToolchainSupport that dumps the symbol tables of the dll, parses it to get the public table and output the table into a .def file. It also says that this may not work if the dll is stripped.

I am not sure if there are good ELF parsers out there in Python. Adding some that I have found.

- http://code.google.com/p/syn-code/source/browse/trunk/freezedis.py

Comment: This is OK but the script is using subprocess module executing objdump to get the symbol table. Do you know a library or python extension ?