# How do I view the list of functions a Linux shared library is exporting?

Tags: linux, export, shared-libraries

I want to view the exported functions of a shared library on Linux.

What command allows me to do this?

(On Windows I use the program depends)

Comment: a similar question: [How do i find out what all symbols are exported from a shared object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237575/how-do-i-find-out-what-all-symbols-are-exported-from-a-shared-object)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out what all symbols are exported from a shared object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237575/how-do-i-find-out-what-all-symbols-are-exported-from-a-shared-object)

Answer (score 412, accepted):

What you need is `nm` and its `-D` option:

```
$ nm -D /usr/lib/libopenal.so.1
.
.
.
00012ea0 T alcSetThreadContext
000140f0 T alcSuspendContext
         U atanf
         U calloc
.
.
.
```

Exported sumbols are indicated by a `T`. Required symbols that must be loaded from other shared objects have a `U`. Note that the symbol table does not include just functions, but exported variables as well.

See the `nm` [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) for more information.

Comment: Or if you only want to see exported symbols, add the "--defined-only" flag. eg:  "nm -D --defined-only /lib/libtest.so"

Comment: On Mac OS X just use `nm` without the `-D` flag.

Comment: nm -D  libmy.so | grep " T "

Comment: And add -C if C++ name-demangling is desired

Answer (score 71):

`objdump -T *.so` may also do the job

Answer (score 16):

Among other already mentioned tools you can use also `readelf` ([manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html)). It is similar to `objdump` but goes more into detail. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8979687/2083355) for the difference explanation.

```
$ readelf -sW /lib/liblzma.so.5 |head -n10

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 128 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND pthread_mutex_unlock@GLIBC_2.0 (4)
     2: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND pthread_mutex_destroy@GLIBC_2.0 (4)
     3: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
     4: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND memmove@GLIBC_2.0 (5)
     5: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND free@GLIBC_2.0 (5)
     6: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND memcpy@GLIBC_2.0 (5)
```

Comment: How am I supposed to find exported symbols by using readelf? It gives me an overwhelming amount of output.

Comment: @JurajMartinka `readelf -sW *.so > out.txt` this will write the output into the file.

Answer (score 7):

On a MAC, you need to use `nm *.o | c++filt`, as there is no `-C` option in `nm`.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case some Mac user is looking here, use llvm-cxxdump or llvm-readelf -sW