# Why does objdump not show .bss, .shstratab, .symtab and .strtab sections?

Tags: c, elf, objdump

I'm currently doing my own objdump implementation in C.

For my `-s` option, I have to show the full contents of the sections of an ELF file.

I'm doing it well, but I'm showing more sections than the "real" objdump.

In fact, it does not output the `.bss`, `.shstrtab`, `.symtab` and `.strtab` sections.

I'm looking around the `sh_flags` value on the `Shdr` struct but I can't find any logic...

Why does `objdump -s <ELF file>` not show these sections ?

Comment: ELF is quite complex, GNU `objdump` is based on BFD, a library which does the heavy lifting (part of binutils).

Comment: Yeah, I know about the BFD library. On the apple open sources, I can see `(section->flags & SEC_HAS_CONTENTS)` to show or not the section. On my computer, .bss has the same flags than other sections that are showed.

Comment: @user1746732 In the original edit, you included `.comment` in the list of sections `objdump` didn't show, but later edited to remove it. Why was this? Did you find that `.comment` was output and you hadn't noticed it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Why objdump -s does not shows these sections ?

Objdump is based on `libbfd`, which abstracts away many complexities of ELF, and was written when objects tended to *only* have three sections.

As such, `objdump` is quite *deficient*. In addition to not showing you (some) existing sections, it may also "synthesize" sections that don't exist at all, and do other weird tricks. This is more of a `libbfd` fault -- its abstraction layer simply doesn't tell objdump about the "missing" sections.

TL;DR: don't use `objdump`. Use `readelf` instead.

Comment: Ok, so this behaviour is not really wanted ? For my objdump I'll show every section. Thank you ! Btw I also prefer to use readelf, objdump is a school project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979664/readelf-vs-objdump-why-are-both-needed

Answer (score 0):

Try using sh_size and sh_type, instead of sh_flags.

Quoting from the [ELF specification](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf)

> **sh_size** This member gives the section’s size in bytes. Unless the
>   section type is SHT_NOBITS, the section occupies sh_size bytes in the
>   ﬁle. A section of type SHT_NOBITS may have a non-zero size, but it
>   occupies no space in the ﬁle

Comment: It seems that only .bss and .got are of type SHT_NOBITS. So it does not explain why .shstrtab, .symtab and .strtab are not shown...

Comment: Here is my conclusion : a section is shown if it has at least one flag (unlike .shstrtab, .symtab and .strtab) or if his type is not NOBITS (unlike .bss). Somebody have another idea ?

Comment: So, i found a cons-exemple :  .gnu_debuglink has no flag and is shown by objdump -s