# What happens when an executable can't find a symbol in dynamic library?

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries, openocd

I would like to use openOCD as my debugger to interact with the J-Link adapter on my board. So I download the code from a mirror repository [openocd - github](https://github.com/openocd-org/openocd) and follow the step in README to build it.

```
  ./bootstrap (when building from the git repository)
  ./configure [options]
  make
  sudo make install
```

And the **configure** threw a error:

```
configure: error: libjaylink-0.2 is required for the SEGGER J-Link Programmer
```

So I built **libjaylink** from [libjaylink - gitlab](https://gitlab.zapb.de/libjaylink/libjaylink)
and finally got **libjaylink.a** and **libjaylink.so** in **/usr/local/lib**.

After that the build process is smooth and link all the object files into an executable **./src/openocd**:

```
libtool: link: ( cd "src/.libs" && rm -f "libopenocd.la" && ln -s "../libopenocd.la" "libopenocd.la" )
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wformat-security -Wshadow -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wredundant-decls -Wpointer-arith -Wundef -Werror -g -O2   -o src/openocd src/main.o src/libopenocd.la  ./jimtcl/libjim.a  -lutil -ldl 
libtool: link: gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wformat-security -Wshadow -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wredundant-decls -Wpointer-arith -Wundef -Werror -g -O2 -o src/openocd src/main.o  src/.libs/libopenocd.a -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libjaylink.so -lusb-1.0 -lm ./jimtcl/libjim.a -lutil -ldl
```

In my limited experience with linking, the global function symbol in **libjaylink.so** should be callable in **./src/openocd**.

But openocd threw an error when running:

```
$ ./src/openocd -f interface/jlink.cfg target/stm32f4x.cfg

./src/openocd: symbol lookup error: ./src/openocd: undefined symbol: jaylink_device_get_usb_bus_ports
```

But it should be in **libjaylink.so**

```
$ objdump -t /usr/local/lib/libjaylink.so

...
0000000000004150 g     F .text  00000000000000c9              jaylink_device_get_usb_bus_ports
0000000000004110 g     F .text  0000000000000036              jaylink_device_get_usb_address
...
```

Wanted to know if there's something I overlook in dynamic linking or there's some step I can follow to find out problem. orz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens when an executable can't find a symbol in dynamic library?

When the executable calls a function (`jaylink_device_get_usb_bus_ports()` here), the runtime loader (`ld-linux` here) searches all the shared libraries loaded into the current process, and if the symbol can't be found in any of them, the process is terminated (by calling `_exit`).

> `objdump ...`

You should *not* call `objdump` on ELF binaries for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22188584/50617). Use `readelf -s` instead. Here the better choice would be to use `nm -D` instead.

> some step I can follow to find out problem.

The first order of business is to verify that `libjaylink.so` in fact defines the `jaylink_device_get_usb_bus_ports()` as an *exported* function:

```
nm -D /usr/local/lib/libjaylink.so | grep jaylink_device_get_usb_bus_ports
```

If the output looks anything other than `...hex-address... T jaylink_device_get_usb_bus_ports`, then it doesn't (and that would need to be debugged separately).

If the output *does* look correct, you next need to find out whether your `./src/openocd` binary is *actually* using the version of the library you think it is using. Run `ldd ./src/openocd`, chances are there is some *other* version of `libjaylink.so` somewhere on your system.

If the correct library is used, and that library does define the symbol, then further debugging can be accomplished by running

```
LD_DEBUG=libs,symbols ./src/openocd -f interface/jlink.cfg target/stm32f4x.cfg
```

This will produce a lot of output and will likely provide a clue as to what went wrong.

Comment: That's really helpful! thanks! I've run `ldd ./src/openocd` . Surprisedly,`libjaylink.so` is not listed.

Comment: @Xshell Are you building on Ubuntu / Debian? Does adding `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to the front of `openocd` link line help?

Comment: My fault, bro. I disabled Jlink option and compiled it again for a usable version but I forget about that. And you are right. It chooses another `libjaylink.so` in system path:
`libjaylink.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjaylink.so.0 (0x00007f24d9008000)`