# size utility reports bss=0 when it's not

Tags: elf

Why does the `size` utility report bss=0 when in fact the `.bss` SECTION is 1044 bytes and `_ebss - _bss` is 4 bytes?

```
% arm-size build/test_q.elf
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   3464    1052       0    4516    11a4 build/test_q.elf
% arm-objdump -t build/test_q.elf | grep bss
20000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
20000414 g     O .bss   00000004 _q_wlim
00000d88 g       .bss   00000000 __exidx_end
20000000 g     O .bss   00000014 _q_v
00000d88 g       .bss   00000000 __exidx_start
20000000 g       .bss   00000000 _uni
20000418 g       .bss   00000000 _ebss
20000014 g     O .bss   00000400 _q_buf
20000414 g       .bss   00000000 _bss
%
```

Comment: "in fact the `.bss` SECTION is 1044" -- it probably _isn't_. Use `readelf -WS test_q.elf` to see what the `.bss` section actually looks like. Also, you should ~never use `objdump` on ELF files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22188584/50617