# Listing library functions in GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Is is possible to list all the library functions available in any library/headers in GCC command line?
Anything similar to program like JAVAP which is available for Java?
Thanks.

Comment: A lot of IDEs/text editors will make a list of function prototypes for you.  If you opened up the headers you care about, you could use that to get the information you're looking for, I think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I view the list of functions a Linux shared library is exporting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514745/how-do-i-view-the-list-of-functions-a-linux-shared-library-is-exporting)

Comment: objdump will do something if provided a specific library

Comment: You can list symbols exported by a library with the `nm` command, but it's no substitute for the documentation (the same is true about javap).

Comment: As of the header files, you obviously just *read* them. The functions are already there in plain text.

Comment: While the answer to the proposed duplicate should be applicable, that question is specific to linux, while this question is instead based on the toolchain rather than operating system.

Comment: @NikosC.: on my system, the `<string>` standard header includes, directly or indirectly, more than 70 (that's seventy) other files. You *can* read all of them, but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @n.m. we can  use javap to enlist all the function prototypes, thats not the case with nm.

Comment: `nm` will show argument types (no return types though) of C++ functions on most systems. This is useful sometimes, but you need the documentation anyway.

Comment: @n.m. I doubt that anyone would need to read standard header files. People prefer references instead :-)

Comment: Yes, potentially out-of-date (or even obsolete) documentation is often preferred over source code.

Comment: @devnull: A function prototype tells **absolutely nothing** about its intended usage. Its source code may help but the prototype alone is **worse than useles**.

Comment: @n.m. seems that you forgot that there's something called *man*pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use objdump to list symbols in a shared libraries (or executables):

```
$objdump -T /usr/lib/libclang.so
<...snipped...>
0000000000124150 g    DF .text  00000000000000c1  Base        clang_reparseTranslationUnit
000000000010fe40 g    DF .text  0000000000000021  Base        clang_getNullRange
0000000000135760 g    DF .text  000000000000009f  Base        clang_getPointeeType
0000000000124290 g    DF .text  0000000000000289  Base        clang_parseTranslationUnit
000000000012b790 g    DF .text  0000000000000935  Base        clang_findReferencesInFile
0000000000110b80 g    DF .text  000000000000001c  Base        clang_getRangeEnd
0000000000127d20 g    DF .text  0000000000000022  Base        clang_disposeCodeCompleteResults
0000000000135e10 g    DF .text  0000000000000037  Base        clang_isPODType
```

000000000010f870 g    DF .text  0000000000000025  Base        clang_getTranslationUnitCursor
0000000000129b50 g    DF .text  00000000000002c1  Base        clang_getDiagnosticOption

As you can see it lists the different symbols and their relative address.