# How can I look inside a Linux .so or .a object and see what functions they contain?

Tags: c++, c, unix, static-libraries

The linker can presumably do this, so is there a command-line tool to list functions in object files and tell me the names of functions and their signatures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do `nm Linux.so` and it'll show the functions and variables inside the .so file.

Comment: Likewise for a `.o` or `.a` (static archive) file.  There are options to tell you which object files within an `.a` file contain which symbols, too.

Comment: need a `-D` flag for `.so` file

Answer (score 15):

For a shared library, you have to use:

```
nm -D /path/to/libwhatever.so.<num>
```

Without the `-D`, `nm` dumps **debug** symbols; `-D` refers to the dynamic symbols that are actually used for dynamic linking. From Ubuntu 12 session:

```
$ nm /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 
nm: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: no symbols
$ nm -D /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | tail
0011fc20 T xdr_wrapstring
001202c0 T xdrmem_create
00115540 T xdrrec_create
001157f0 T xdrrec_endofrecord
00115740 T xdrrec_eof
00115690 T xdrrec_skiprecord
00120980 T xdrstdio_create
00120c70 T xencrypt
0011d330 T xprt_register
0011d450 T xprt_unregister
```

On this system `libc.so` is stripped of debug symbols, so `nm` shows nothing; but of course there are symbols for the dynamic linking mechanism revealed by `nm -D`.

For a `.a` archive or `.o` object file, just `nm`. The symbols are the symbols; if these files are stripped, these objects cannot be used for linking.

As covered in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514745/how-do-i-view-the-list-of-functions-a-linux-shared-library-is-exporting/4514781#4514781):

> Exported sumbols are indicated by a `T`. Required symbols that must be loaded from other shared objects have a `U`. Note that the symbol table does not include just functions, but exported variables as well.

> Or if you only want to see exported symbols, add the `--defined-only` flag. eg: `nm -D --defined-only /lib/libtest.so`

Comment: What is U, R, T each explaining ? 
(your here is only T)

Comment: @klenteed R means the symbol is in a read-only data section. U means undefined symbol (reference to a symbol that has to come from somewhere else).  T means that the symbol is in the text section (i.e. code).