# Get function return type and arguments from a shared object file (.so)

Tags: c, dll, clang, shared-libraries, dlopen

So I have this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int helloworld()
{
    return 12;
}
```

And I compile this using:

```sh
gcc -shared -o libhello.so main.c
```

This gives me a `libhello.so` file.

Now, I am loading this function in another project using `dlopen`.
My question is, is there any way for me to "list" functions in the `libhello.so` file, along with their return types and arguments?

I am working with a system where users create plugins using `.so` files, so exactly how the functions are defined is unknown to me.

Basically, I want to dynamically create function pointers for functions defined in the `.so` file.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514745/how-do-i-view-the-list-of-functions-a-linux-shared-library-is-exporting ?

Comment: @babon Yes, I have tried objdump and nm, I dont really see the return type of the function in there though.

And also, I want to be able to retrieve this list from within another C program, not using the command line.

Comment: In short: No there's no simple or standard way. You might build the library with debug information and extract the information from that, but it's not simple. And for a stripped library which don't have debug information, then it's impossible to get that information.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by _plugin_ in your question. Normally when one adds plugins to her app she defines an exact API which _all_ plugins need to provide.

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to parse through a .so file and manage to get function names (assuming that they're not obfuscated). But it is not possible to get the data types of arguments and return type. This is the reason that so files comes with corresponding header files.

Comment: Of *course* you can use even a library function to view the symbols in the `.so` and they must not be mangled for C...