# Is it enough to wrap exported functions of a C library using JNI for it to work using JNI?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am interested about the prospects of using **any** C library using JNI. Particularly with Android, but I assumed this compatibility should be the same as being compatible with JNI.

Without being an original developer of some C library, I've found it confusing to know, what methods I need to register in JNI_OnLoad (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#native-libraries).

To progress, I figured out with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/4514781/4959635 to call

```
nm myclib.a | grep " T "
```

to find a list of (supposed) "exported functions". However, the `nm` output may well tell other things as well.

Now my question is,

**will/could/should a library work, if I wrap only the exported functions via JNI_OnLoad?**

Or do I need to ensure other qualities in the library in order to guarantee that it will work with JNI?

---

On the other hand, I read some other discussions such as:

https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-loading-shared-lib.360242/

which suggested that having undefined symbols might mean that the C code is not structured properly for JNI.

Whereas this resource:

https://www.baeldung.com/jni

seems to suggest that wrapping exported functions is in fact what's expected.

Answer (score 0):

No. Functions you call from JNI must always follow a specific signature: (ignoring the return type for now)

```
fun(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, ...)
```

or

```
fun(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, ...)
```

where the remaining arguments are types that the JVM can process.

You **will** need to create wrapper functions that go between the JVM types and whatever types your functions expect. See the SWIG library for a potential means of auto-generating these wrappers, but know you will still need to write quite a bit of custom code.

Comment: This reinforces the idea that JNI is a painful idea for using C libraries, since it seems to require so much extra work. Is it possible to look for C libraries that are particularly easy to wrap then? A particular further interest is the time spent on writing wrapper code (and understanding how to do it for a particular library) vs a Java implementation.

Comment: "[looking] for C libraries that are particularly easy to wrap" is putting the horse before the cart, I would say. If your real question is "what makes an API easy or hard to integrate with JNI", I would say excessive use of pointer arguments and custom classes. Take a look at the SWIG and JNA projects for some assistance in using native libraries.

Comment: But must the library be designed with a Java wrap in mind in order to it work out? Rather than expect an existing library to just be wrappable without considerable refactoring?

Comment: You can *always* wrap a library in JNI. It is only a matter of effort.

Comment: I believe the required investment is too large for some libraries. Which might be an additional concern. It's the reason I was looking for a workaround like using `nm`.

Comment: I truly do not understand your underlying motivation or goal. The starting point for wrapping a library must always be the public API in the headers, because that also documents the types and arguments.

Comment: My motivation is "can I take *any* C library (or if not *any*, then something that has been labeled as some kind, e.g. header-only) and almost auto-generate a wrapper to it?". Because as a wrapper my interest is not to learn how the source code works.

Comment: If it was that easy somebody would have already done that. No, wrapping APIs requires human intellect because the machine-readable parts of C header files will never tell the full picture.

Comment: But does this then suggest that producing such wrap must be part of the library designer's intention?

Comment: No, where did you get that from? As I said, *any* library can be wrapped. But certain patterns (see above) require extra work.

Comment: This answer has the problem that once passing through the JNI once to some function in C/C++, then one can use all C/C++ as normal without any notion of JNI. The function headers are mandatory only for the top-level function.

Comment: "problem"? You are effectively saying that the JNI code is limited to the bits that Java interfaces with. I never said otherwise.

Comment: Libraries can work regardless of JNI. And they can work without custom code.

Comment: Of course. You only need JNI to **interface with Java**. That should be evident from the name and the documentation.