# capture exported functions from DLL using python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, dllexport

I'm trying to list with python all exported function from any DLL using ctypes, but i don't know if it's possible.
Someone know how can i do it?
I need to implement a script that return all DLL functions, passing as parameter for this script the path of DLL.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57029933/2203828

Comment: unfortunately, already try to implement this script, but doesn't work. I'm using windows 10 and the command "nm" doesn't exists

Comment: As the script expects the use of gcc, it probably expects Cygwin  to be installed (https://www.cygwin.com). That will also provide the `nm` command.

Comment: Possible (but not feasible):  generate all valid identifier names and probe them against the *.dll* :)