# Ctypes implementation in Python

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I am trying to implement a small example for using ctypes in Python. Below are the source code of the files.

project structure:

```
parent
  |____src
        |___sqrt.c
        |___sqrt.h
  |____build
        |___sum.dll
  |____bin.py
```

bin.py

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.util import find_library


def main():
    a = 6;
    lib_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'bbbb', 'Debug','{}.dll'.format("sum"))
    print(lib_path)
    try:
        lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)
    except Exception as e:
        raise RuntimeError("Could not load funnel library with this path: {}. {}".format(lib_path, e))

    lib.root.argtypes= [c_double]
    lib.root.restype = c_double
    try:
        ret = lib.root(a)
    except Exception as e:
        raise RuntimeError("Library call raises exception: {}".format(e)) 

    print(ret)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

sqrt.c

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqrt.h"

double root( double num) {
    if(num <0){
        printf("Num shoulrnot be less than 0");
    return -1;
    }
    return sqrt(num);
    }
```

sqrt.h

```
#ifndef SUM_H_
#define SUM_H_


double root( double num);

#endif
```

But when executed it is showing the following error:

```
AttributeError: function 'root' not found
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you check that the DLL is indeed providing the function `root`?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean, No. I am new to ctypes and i dont how to check it.

Comment: It's not linked to ctypes, you can do it with a tool on Windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891493/list-exported-functions-from-dll-with-ctypes

Comment: Your script works on my system. Show the compilation commands you used.

Comment: What OS?  On Windows you need to explicitly export the function from the DLL, e.g.`__declspec(dllexport) double root(double num)`.